# How would program/create a custom NFC reader-writer?

Tags: microcontroller, nfc

I'm trying to create a custom NFC reader/writer. I've been able to use a linux machine with  Eclipse to write a java program (and daemon) that controls a reader writer like an ACR122U. So basically on shutdown and startup, it can read nfc data and then transmit it. But now I want to downsize this. I want to put breadboard together a device that is way smaller (palm of your hand)  that reads an NFC tag/phone and transmits it back through a serial port (I'm assuming that's easiest). I understand I need a microcontroller and a PN5XX chip. I'm thinking I need a flash rom to put the instructions on. Does anyone know how I could get started creating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by using an Arduino paired with [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/789) shield to interface with NFC tags. The Arduino is capable of communicating with the PC over USB.

Once you have a prototype built with the Arduino and NFC breakout board you could buy all the required components in miniature discreet form.

Comment: Hi conor, thanks for the input. I've decided to use a ATMEL microcontroller in conjunction with the PN532 Breakout board (as you had suggested) as a start. Arduino would be nice, but I think I can use a smaller microcontroller to satisfy the simplistic nature of what I need it to do. Newbiehack.com had a very informative tutorial about MCU programming for me to follow.

Comment: Interesting site.. I'm just getting started in Robotics. Glad to help :)